# Relative image source path returns null using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, image, relative-path

i've got a problem I need help with.

I am trying to create a mouseover animation using jQuery so that when a user hover over an image it shows a highlighted version of the image. I know I can do this with CSS, the problem is however that the content needs to be managed. So i wanted to write a function that matches a part of the image filename and use a wildcard for the rest of the filename.

Here is the HTML:
This is the image that will always be shown unless a user hover over the image.

```
<img class="imgPath" src="<?php echo PATH_SITE. 'uploads/folder/bgr_img.jpg' ?>" alt="First Image" />
```

When the user hover over the image, I would like to change the src:

```
<img class="imgPath" src="<?php echo PATH_SITE. 'uploads/folder/hvr_image.jpg' ?>" alt="First Image" />
```

On mouseout I would like the src to return to its previous state "bgr_image.jpg"

This is the jQuery I am using currently:

```
$(function() {
    $(".imgPath")
        .mouseover(function() { 
            var src = $(this).attr("src").match("http://domain.com/path/to/img/hvr_image.jpg");
            $(this).attr("src", src);
        })
        .mouseout(function() {
            var src = $(this).attr("src").replace("http://domain.com/path/to/img/hvr_image.jpg", "http://domain.com/path/to/img/bgr_image.jpg");
            $(this).attr("src", src);
        });
});
```

If I hover over the image right now, it will change the src to "null". I tried to use the path name without the domain included but it returns the same value.

Help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you match your src or replace it? Just change it:

```
$(function() { 
    $(".imgPath").hover(
        function() { $(this).attr("src", "http://domain.com/path/to/img/hvr_image.jpg"); },
        function() { $(this).attr("src", "http://domain.com/path/to/img/bgr_image.jpg"); }
    ); 
});
```

**EDIT:**

match() returns an array of the matches: Access your src with [0]

```
$(function() { 
    $(".imgPath") 
        .mouseover(function() {  
            var src = $(this).attr("src").match("http://domain.com/path/to/img/hvr_image.jpg"); 
            $(this).attr("src", src[0]); 
        }) 
        .mouseout(function() { 
            var src = $(this).attr("src").replace("http://domain.com/path/to/img/hvr_image.jpg", "http://domain.com/path/to/img/bgr_image.jpg"); 
            $(this).attr("src", src); 
        }); 
});
```

**EDIT2:**

```
<img class="imgPath" onmouseover="changeImgSrc(this, '<?php echo PATH_SITE. 'uploads/folder/hvr_image.jpg' ) ?>'" onmouseout="changeImgSrc(this, '<?php echo PATH_SITE. 'uploads/folder/bgr_image.jpg' ) ?>'" src="<?php echo PATH_SITE. 'uploads/folder/bgr_image.jpg' ?>" alt="FirstImage" />

<script>
    function changeImgSrc(img, imgsrc) {
        $(img).attr('src', imgsrc);
    }
</script>
```

OR:

```
<img class="imgPath" onmouseover="this.src = '<?php echo PATH_SITE. 'uploads/folder/hvr_image.jpg' ) ?>'" onmouseout="this.src = '<?php echo PATH_SITE. 'uploads/folder/bgr_image.jpg' ) ?>'" src="<?php echo PATH_SITE. 'uploads/folder/bgr_image.jpg' ?>" alt="FirstImage" />
```

Comment: Because I would like to use wildcards so that I can be applied to all the images in that section of the website. This method can only be applied to 1 instance, how could I apply it for lets say, 5 images with 5 different names. Write the functon 5 times over? Seems sloppy.

Comment: It still returns null. if I use the same image in the match function, that is loaded. It wont show any errors because there is a match and the src is not null. However if try to match it to an image for its hover state, it will tell me the src is null.

Comment: I added a new solution in my post (EDIT2). Maybe this can help you.

Comment: It clutters the html, but it will have to do, thank you for your time Andreas. It works fine. :)

Answer (score 0):

The "match" function returns a boolean, not a string (in mouseover function)

Comment: no, "match" returns the matches in an array or null if no match.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to use **match()** and **replace()** function with this task

**Do as following.**

```
$(function() {
    $(".imgPath")
        .mouseover(function() { 

            $(this).attr("src", "http://domain.com/path/to/img/bgr_image.jpg");

        })
        .mouseout(function() {
            $(this).attr("src", "http://domain.com/path/to/img/hvr_image.jpg");

        });
});
```

**EDITED:**

Let say if you have this kind of scenario for multiple images:

```
<div class="imgPath"><img src="1.jpg" /> </div>
<div class="imgPath"><img src="2.jpg"  /></div>
<div class="imgPath"><img src="3.jpg" /> </div>
<div class="imgPath"><img src="4.jpg"  /></div>
```

So we can manage this with below code:

```
$('.imgPath img').hover(
    function(){
        $('.imgPath img').each(
            function(){
                $(this).attr("src", "http://domain.com/path/to/img/bgr_image.jpg");
            });
    },
    function(){
        $('.imgPath img').each(
            function(){
              $(this).attr("src", "http://domain.com/path/to/img/hvr_image.jpg");
            });
    }

);
```

I think this will help you more.

Thanks.

Comment: Yes this works, just like the previous answer. However I would like to apply this to multiple images. With this method I can only apply it to 1 image.

Comment: Please check my Edited portion of the Answer. Thanks